# Changing the launch directory of executable in MSVC

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

My folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
bin -> data -> blurf.xml
lib -> blurb.lib
src -> blah.cpp
msvc -> project_name -> project_name.sln ...
....
```

Here is my issue. This project needs to run on Linux and Windows
So I need that when I build it in MSVC, the exe ends up in ../../bin

This is because my application has a data folder and the application expects to find in the root where the exe is.

Is there a way that when I run a build, it thinks it is (or is) in the ../../bin directory so it accesses the data folder?

If not, is there some other way I can have it know where its data is when I run from MSVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project properties, Debugging sheet and set 'Working directory' accordingly